# Convert a set of ratings (where lower number is better) into a probability in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I have the following dataframe which is a set of ratings for individuals in a sporting competition.

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'EventNo': ['10','10','10','10'],
    'Name': ['Joe','Jack','John','James'],
    'Rating':[30,35,2.5,3],
    }
             
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

The rating is an ascending scale, where the lower the number means a higher rating (i.e `John` is the highest rated competitor and `Jack` is the lowest).

I am trying to convert these ratings into a probability. I came across this from the stats stack exchange:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277298/create-a-higher-probability-to-smaller-values

But I am struggling to apply this into the pandas dataframe problem like this. I would like it grouped by `EventNo` so in my example all 4 of these rows add up to 1 (100%)

Has anyone been able to do this type of calculation in Python? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Are you okay with any transformation on `Rating` as long as they sum up to 1 at the end and the negated order you mention is preserved? i.e., any contraints on invertibility of the transformation etc.

Comment: Im not too sure what you mean by constraints but I basically have many groups of ratings like this that I would like to apply a probability to. I guess every transformation has its pros and cons is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, there might be many transformations that satisfy that. For example: `df["probs"] = df.groupby("EventNo").Rating.transform(lambda x: (1/x) / (1/x).sum())`. Is this fine? Takes the inverse (to get a reverse order) and normalizes by the sum (to get a probability-like values).

Comment: thanks @MustafaAydın! I will have a go at this. Could you point me in the direction of some other transformations?

Comment: As in an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/277324/285512) of the question you linked says, any monotonically decreasing function will do fine, i.e., it will reverse the order between values. Then you can always divide the transformed values by their sum to "normalize" them such that the final values sum to 1 to look like a probability distribution. For example, you can replace `(1/x)` above with `(2**-x)`. The difference between them is the final values themselves but all such transformations preserve the order and make the final values sum to 1 this way or another.